# Terraform how to interpolate map types in a template_file?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to pass a map variable into a template_file, and am being thrown this error:

vars (varsname): '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type 'map[string]interface {}'

```
    data "template_file" "app" {

        template = "${file("./app_template.tpl")}"

        vars {
                container = "${var.container-configuration}"
        }
    }
```

variables.tf

```
    variable "container-configuration" {
        description = "Configuration for container"
        type        = "map"
        default     = {
                    image          = "blahblah.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/connect"
                    container-port = "3000"
                    host-port      = "3000"
                    cpu            = "1024"
                    memory         = "2048"
                    log-group      = "test"
                    log-region     = "us-east-2a"
                  }
    }
```

Is there a way to pass the map into the template file for interpolation? I haven't found anything clear in the documentation.

Comment: there is a suggested solution in an other thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62585889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing maps is not yet supported, see [template_file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) documentation.

From that article:

> Variables must all be primitives. Direct references to lists or maps will cause a validation error.

It means you need to pass variables one by one individually.

Comment: It seems, it does support maps though: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile
(your link isn't working though)

Answer (score 8):

Terraform v0.12 introduced the [`templatefile`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) function, which absorbs the main use-cases of the `template_file` data source, and accepts values of any type:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/app_template.tpl", {
  container = var.container-configuration
})
```

Terraform v0.11 and earlier do not have any means to render a template with non-string values. The limitation exists due to the nature of the protocol used to represent map values in the configuration: it is only capable of representing maps of string until the new protocol that was introduced in Terraform v0.12.

Comment: How is this actually used though, for instance in a `local-exec`?