# How do I read values of a variable of type Map passed from terraform to powershell userdata script?

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to pass the variable of type map from terraform to powershell userdata script and be able to access the key value pairs of the map in the powershell script. Thank you

*userdata.tf*

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/init.ps1")}"
  vars = {
    environment = var.env
    # I want to pass the values as shown below
    hostnames   = {"dev":"devhost","test":"testhost","prod":"prodhost"}
  }
}
```

init.ps1

```
$hostnames = "${hostnames}"
$environment = "${environment}"

if ($environment -eq "dev"){
   # print the value of the dev key in the hostname map here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [template_file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) data source is discouraged.

> Note In Terraform 0.12 and later, [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) offers a built-in mechanism for rendering a template from a file. Use that function instead, unless you are using Terraform 0.11 or earlier.

The [templatefile function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) is preferred which is why my solution uses it instead.

In either case, only **map(string)** is supported for template vars. The values *must* be strings. JSON can encode arbitrary tree structures, including your map of hostnames as strings.

In your terraform code, encode your **hostnames** to JSON with [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html).

userdata.tf:

```
locals {
  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/init.ps1" ,{
    environment = var.env
    # I want to pass the values as shown below
    hostnames   = jsonencode({"dev":"devhost","test":"testhost","prod":"prodhost"})
  })
}
```

In your PowerShell, decode your **hostnames** from JSON with [the ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7).

init.ps1:

```
$hostnames = '${hostnames}' | ConvertFrom-Json
$environment = "${environment}"

if ($environment -eq "dev"){
   # print the value of the dev key in the hostname map here
}
```

Update: As noted in the comments, `-AsHashtable` won't necessarily work as it was added in PowerShell 6.0. Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 include PowerShell 5.1. If you have maps with case-only differences in keys (`{"name" = "foo" ; "Name" = "bar"}`) then you will need to install PowerShell 6.0 or later and use `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable`.

Comment: `-AsHashTable` did not work in my powershell 5.1, modified the code as below to work for me
`$hostnames = '${hostnames}' | ConvertFrom-Json;
$hostname = $hostnames.$environment;
Write-Output "New Hostname: $hostname"`

Comment: Thank you! Fixed and noted the compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to include a collection value in a template result you must decide how you want to represent it as a string, because template results are always strings.

PowerShell supports JSON encoding via [the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7), so a JSON string might be a good candidate, although it presents some challenges because you must ensure that the JSON string is written into the result as a valid PowerShell expression, which means we must also apply PowerShell escaping.

Putting that all together, you can adjust the template like this:

```
$hostnames = '${replace(jsonencode(hostnames), "'", "''")}' | ConvertFrom-Json
$environment = '${replace(environment, "'", "''")}'

if ($environment -eq "dev"){
   Write-Output $hostnames["dev"]
}
```

The `jsonencode` function produces a JSON-encoded version of the given value. The above then passes that result to `replace` so that any `'` characters in the result will be escaped as `''`, which then allows placing the entire result in single quotes `'` to ensure valid PowerShell syntax.

The result of rendering the template would be something like this:

```
$hostnames = '{"dev":"devhost","test":"testhost","prod":"prodhost"}' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
$environment = 'dev'

if ($environment -eq "dev"){
   Write-Output $hostnames["dev"]
}
```

You seem to be using Terraform 0.12, so you should use [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) instead of the `template_file` data source. The function is better because it can accept values of any type, whereas the data source can only accept string values (because it is designed for Terraform 0.11).

To use `templatefile`, find the place where you were previously referring to data.template_file.user_data and use the `templatefile` function there instead:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/init.ps1", {
  environment = var.env
  hostnames   = {"dev":"devhost","test":"testhost","prod":"prodhost"}
})
```

You can then remove the `data "template_file" "user_data"` block, because this `templatefile` function call replaces it.